# The word "the" causing syntax error in print function - Python

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm using "The coder's apprentice: Learning Python with Python 3" (http://www.spronck.net/pythonbook/pythonbook.pdf).

I'm doing this exercise: "The cover price of a book is $24.95, but bookstores get a 40 percent discount.
Shipping costs $3 for the first copy and 75 cents for each additional copy. Calculate the total wholesale costs for 60 copies."

This is my code:

```
book_price = 24.95
book_discount = book_price / 10 * 4
bookstore_book_price = book_price - book_discount
shipping_first = 3
shipping_rest = 0.75
sixty_shipped = bookstore_book_price + shipping_first + (shipping_rest * 59)
print("A book is being sold regularly for " +str(book_price) + ".")
print("At bookstores, it's being sold with a 40% discount, amounting to " + str(book_discount) + ".")
print("This means it's being sold at bookstores for " + str(bookstore_book_price) + ".")
print("The first copy ships for " + "str(shipping_first) + ", but the rest ships for " + str(shipping_rest) ".")
print("Given 60 copies were shipped, it would cost " + str(sixty_shipped + ".")
```

For whatever reason, the word `the` in this line of code:

```
(print("The first copy ships for " + "str(shipping_first) + ", but the rest ships for " + str(shipping_rest) "."))`
```

Produces a syntax error. Given that I remove each word until I reach `for` I still get a syntax error. When only `for` and `but` are left, the error:

> EOL while scanning string literal

is produced. I don't have a clue what to do.

Here's my code: [Using IDLE editor (not prompt).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuKja.png)

Comment: Remove the `"` in `"str(shipping_first)`. Also, missing `)` in `str(sixty_shipped` and missing `+` after `str(shipping_rest)`. Closing for typos. Also, you might want to have a look at [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Even stackoverflows syntax hightlighter shows your error :)

Comment: Your quotes are not matching. you can clearly see that from the formatting of the strings in your `print`

Answer (score 1):

Because you got an extra `"`. Instead of

```
(print("The first copy ships for " + "str(shipping_first) + ", but the rest ships for " + str(shipping_rest) "."))
```

do

```
(print("The first copy ships for " + str(shipping_first) + ", but the rest ships for " + str(shipping_rest) + "."))
```

You can also omit calling `str()`, from [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) docs:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream

**UPD**

Also you skipped `+` at the end of error line.
And as @tobias_k mentioned you forgot closing `)` for `str` method `print("Given 60 copies were shipped, it would cost " + str(sixty_shipped + ".")`

So for your code to work without `str()` methods:

```
print("The first copy ships for ", shipping_first, ", but the rest ships for ", shipping_rest, ".")
```

Or even better with [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
print("The first copy ships for {}, but the rest ships for {}.".format(shipping_first, shipping_rest))
```

It's now more readable.

Comment: Note that there is at least one more typo in the last line.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks, i believe i mentioned all the typos OP got(updated answer).